# jquery or javascript - add text from text editor into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a webpage with a textbox named "title" and a text editor window that represents content.
I have this javascript variable:

```
var article = {"title" : "I am a title", "content" : "I am the content"};
```

I must admit and I've never ran into this kind of array before in javascript, that's why I need help.

Here's my code of the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        var article = {"title" : "I am a title", "content" : "I am the content"};
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" method="post">
        <label>Title:</label><br />
        <input id="myTitle"></input><br /><br />
        <label>Content:</label><br />
        <textarea id="myContent" name="myContent" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
</textarea><br /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to add to the webpage functionality is this:

1. When page loads, put in the title textbox and inside the textarea (where the text editor is) the values in the article variable (in this case "I am a title" in the title, and "I am the content" in the editor).
2. Once I change the values inside those textbox and textarea, the variable itself should be updated to what I've written.

Unfortunately for me, I have never ran into this kind of variable, so I'd be glad for some guidance.

Comment: That's called an _object_.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've tried to search help and relized that I can get the best kind of it right here. Honestly, I don't know where to start and with what.

Comment: Probably helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Are you allowed to use a JavaScript framework like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var article = {
    "title": "I am a title",
    "content": "I am the content"
};

$('#myTitle').val(article.title);
$('#myContent').val(article.content);

$('#target').click(function() {
    article.title = $('#myTitle').val();
    article.content = $('#myContent').val();
    alert(article.title + '\n' + article.content);
    return false;
});​
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc4XD/)

Comment: it dosen't work in my page, but in your demo it does. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, have you set the `id` to the submit button as `target`?

Comment: I hav set the `id` like this `<input type="submit" value="save" id="target" />​`...

Comment: `it dosen't work in my page` what is not working?? To be specific!!

Comment: Sorry @Palash, now I got it work except for one thing: The content textarea is a wysiwyg editor and not a plain textarea, so I don't get the "This is the content" initial value inside.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good choice to use knockout for this. First of all I would recommend you to read documentation of knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

To track object status you should use `ko.observable`. Put the following code to the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var article = {
           title: ko.observable("I am a title"),
           content: ko.observable("I am the content")
        };

    ko.applyBindings(article);
</script>
```

And update your form as follow:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
    <label>Title:</label><br />
    <input id="myTitle" data-bind="value: title"></input>
    <br /><br />
    <label>Content:</label><br />
    <textarea id="myContent" data-bind="value: content" name="myContent" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
</textarea><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8gJAZ/

EDIT:

Also don't forget to add reference to knockout library.

```
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: Did you reference knockout.js ?

Comment: Now I did and it worked :) thanks! but when I click 'save' it goes back to the same initial values. why?

Comment: Because after submit you load the page again and script sets the same value. You should set values of article object to values from server. What server side technology do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is "how to use `object`". You can use it by:

```
var title = article.title;
var content = article.content;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using closures for this purpose. You can use public members commented below by dot syntax. You may also want to extend and add functionality.

```
var Article = (function() {

    var title = "";
    var content = "";

    function setOrUpdateValues(t, c) {
        title = (t !== null) ? t : title;
        content = (c !== null) ? c : content;
    }

    function getValues() {
        return {
            title: title,
            content: content
        }
    }

    function setTitle(t) {
        title = t;
    }

    function setContent(c) {
        content = c;
    }

    function getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    function getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    // public members
    return {
        title: title,
        content: content,
        getValues: getValues,
        setOrUpdateValues: setOrUpdateValues,
        updateTitle: setTitle,
        updateContent: setContent,
        getTitle: getTitle,
        getContent: getContent
    }
}());


// usage

Article.setOrUpdateValues("title", "content");

printValues();

Article.updateTitle("updated title");

printValues();

Article.setOrUpdateValues(null, "newContent");

printValues();

function printValues() {
    var values = Article.getValues();
    console.log("title: " + values.title + ", content: " + values.content);
}
```